# add data to array with button java

Tags: java, arrays, swing, user-interface

I am building a simple project. I have an array which contains a list of items that my 'shop'(app) is using. These items have some default values, such as quantity, description and price.

Here is an example:

```
public appManage initTools(){
    items = new Utilities[10];
    items[0] = new Utilities(250, "Screw", 2.50);
    items[1] = new Utilities(200, "Knife", 3.00);
    items[2] = new Utilities(60, "Hammer", 3.50);
    return this;
```

And of course

```
public Utilities(int quantity, String description, double price) {
    super();
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.description = description;
    this.price = price;
}
```

What I want to do is create a small JOptionPane/JFrame that allows the user to input a quantity,description and price(in other terms to create add an item to the array). So for example, after the user types in 3 different textboxes, a

```
items[3] = new Utilities(textbox1, textbox2, textbox3);
```

is created.
Is that possible cause I think I am missing something.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please say the problem clearly. In addition, you need some Convert methods in parameters of new Utilities.

Comment: I need help creating the method in which I am gonna parse the 3 Textfield inputs and put them into items[]. Is it possible?

Comment: check: `new Utilities(Integer.parseInt(textbox1.getText() , textbox2.getText() , Long.parseLong(textbox3.getText());`

Comment: Will this go to items[3] though? (I will come back to you, I am implementing it)

Comment: yes, `item[3]=new Utilities(Integer.parseInt(textbox1.getText() , textbox2.getText() , Long.parseLong(textbox3.getText());` , Notice that your textbox1 and textbox2 and textbox3 are instances of JTextField.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I need some time to get to my main pc. Once I implement it I am gonna ask here if I got any other issues.